# Hyperledger Fabric grpcs error: Connection Refused: no further information,JAVA SDK

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I have been trying out to invoke and querying transactions from the Java SDK for the BYFN network in Hyperledger Fabric v1.4.4 So far i have started the network (which has two peers in two orgs, an orderer and chaincode mycc installed). The network starts successfully, and scripts and tests complete.

This is my Java SDK code to manipulate the network from Java and do queries and invokes

Main class:

```
public class sdksample {

    // Main program to simply call the client, Am i making some mistake here ?? persistency ?
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create fabric-ca client
        BlockChainHFClient.getInstance().setupCryptoMaterialsForClient();
        BlockChainHFClient.getInstance().initChannel();

        // get HFC client instance
        BlockChainHFClient client = BlockChainHFClient.getInstance();
        System.out.println(client);

    }
}
```

BlockchainClient Class:

```
public class BlockChainHFClient {

    private static BlockChainHFClient instance;

    /**
     * Client instance constructor
     */
    private BlockChainHFClient() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns an instance of the Fabric client
     * 
     * @return instance
     */
    public static synchronized BlockChainHFClient getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new BlockChainHFClient();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /**
     * Fabric client object
     */
    final HFClient hfClient = HFClient.createNewInstance();
    /**
     * Crypto config folder location . keep crypto-config folder in user/home
     */
    final String CRYPTO_CONFIG_HOME_DIR = System.getProperty("user.home");
    /**
     * Grpcs URL
     */
    final String GRPCS = "grpcs://";
    /**
     * Dot for utility
     */
    final String DOT = ".";
    /**
     * MSP ID Root
     */
    final String ROOT_MSP_ID = "Org1MSP";
    /**
     * Admin user
     */
    final String PEER_ADMIN = "PeerAdmin";
    /**
     * Channel object
     */
    Channel channel;

    /**
     * Channel initialize timeout values
     */
    final Long ChannelBuilderOptionkeepAliveMinutes = 15L;
    final Long ChannelBuilderOptionkeepAliveSeconds = 15L;

    /**
     * Get channel instance
     * 
     * @return channel
     */
    public Channel getChannel() {
        return channel;
    }

    /**
     * Get HF client
     * 
     * @return HF client
     */
    public HFClient getClient() {
        return hfClient;
    }

    /**
     * Set up User contexts by using Crypto materials - Private key and cert files
     * 
     * @throws CryptoException
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException
     * @throws IllegalAccessException
     * @throws InstantiationException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     * @throws NoSuchMethodException
     * @throws InvocationTargetException
     */
    public void setupCryptoMaterialsForClient()
            throws CryptoException, InvalidArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException,
            ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
        hfClient.setCryptoSuite(CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite());
        hfClient.setUserContext(new User() {
            public String getName() {
                return PEER_ADMIN;
            }

            public Set<String> getRoles() {
                return null;
            }

            public String getAccount() {
                return null;
            }

            public String getAffiliation() {
                return null;
            }

            public Enrollment getEnrollment() {
                return new Enrollment() {
                    public PrivateKey getKey() {
                        PrivateKey privateKey = null;
                        File privateKeyFile = findFileSk(
                                "D:\\Hyperledger Fabric_Research_Blockchain\\Fabric1.4.4\\fabric-samples\\first-network\\crypto-config\\peerOrganizations\\org1.example.com\\users\\Admin@org1.example.com\\msp\\keystore");
                        try {
                            privateKey = getPrivateKeyFromBytes(
                                    IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile)));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return privateKey;
                    }

                    public String getCert() {

                        String certificate = null;
                        try {
                            File certificateFile = new File(
                                    "D:\\Hyperledger Fabric_Research_Blockchain\\Fabric1.4.4\\fabric-samples\\first-network\\crypto-config\\peerOrganizations\\org1.example.com\\users\\Admin@org1.example.com\\msp\\signcerts\\Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem");
                            certificate = new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(certificateFile)),
                                    "UTF-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return certificate;
                    }
                };
            }

            public String getMspId() {
                return ROOT_MSP_ID;
            }
        });
    }

    public void initChannel() throws Exception {
        Properties peerProperties = new Properties();
        peerProperties.setProperty("pemFile",
                "D:\\Hyperledger Fabric_Research_Blockchain\\Fabric1.4.4\\fabric-samples\\first-network\\crypto-config\\peerOrganizations\\org1.example.com\\peers\\peer0.org1.example.com\\tls\\server.crt");
        peerProperties.setProperty("trustServerCertificate", "true"); // testing environment only NOT FOR PRODUCTION!
        peerProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", "peer0.org1.example.com");
        peerProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
        peerProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
        peerProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.maxInboundMessageSize", 9000000);
        Peer peer = hfClient.newPeer("peer0.org1.example.com", "grpcs://localhost:7051");


        Properties ordererProperties = new Properties();
        ordererProperties.setProperty("pemFile",
                "D:\\Hyperledger Fabric_Research_Blockchain\\Fabric1.4.4\\fabric-samples\\first-network\\crypto-config\\ordererOrganizations\\example.com\\orderers\\orderer.example.com\\tls\\server.crt");
        ordererProperties.setProperty("trustServerCertificate", "true"); // testing environment only NOT FOR PRODUCTION!
        ordererProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", "orderer.example.com");
        ordererProperties.setProperty("sslProvider", "openSSL");
        ordererProperties.setProperty("negotiationType", "TLS");
        ordererProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.keepAliveTime", new Object[] { 5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES });
        ordererProperties.put("grpc.NettyChannelBuilderOption.keepAliveTimeout", new Object[] { 8L, TimeUnit.SECONDS });
        Orderer orderer = hfClient.newOrderer("orderer.example.com", "grpcs://localhost:7050");


        Channel channel = hfClient.newChannel("mychannel");
        channel.addPeer(peer);
        channel.addOrderer(orderer);
        channel.initialize();



        moveUnits(hfClient);
        queryBlockChain(hfClient);

    }

    private String printableString(String string) {
        int maxLogStringLength = 10000;
        if (string == null || string.length() == 0) {
            return string;
        }

        String ret = string.replaceAll("[^\\p{Print}]", "\n");

        ret = ret.substring(0, Math.min(ret.length(), maxLogStringLength))
                + (ret.length() > maxLogStringLength ? "..." : "");

        return ret;
    }

    void queryBlockChain(HFClient client) throws ProposalException, InvalidArgumentException {
        // get channel instance from client
        Channel channel = client.getChannel("mychannel");
        // create chaincode request
        QueryByChaincodeRequest qpr = client.newQueryProposalRequest();
        // build cc id providing the chaincode name. Version is omitted here.
        ChaincodeID cid = ChaincodeID.newBuilder().setName("mycc").build();
        qpr.setChaincodeID(cid);
        // CC function to be called
        qpr.setFcn("query");
        qpr.setArgs(new String[] { "a" });
        Collection<ProposalResponse> res = channel.queryByChaincode(qpr);
        // display response
        for (ProposalResponse pres : res) {
            String stringResponse = new String(pres.getChaincodeActionResponsePayload());
            System.out.println(stringResponse);
        }
    }

     void moveUnits(HFClient client)
                throws Exception {
            Channel channel = client.getChannel("mychannel");
            TransactionProposalRequest req = client.newTransactionProposalRequest();
            ChaincodeID cid = ChaincodeID.newBuilder().setName("mycc").setVersion("1.0").build();
            req.setChaincodeID(cid);
            req.setFcn("invoke");
            req.setArgs(new String[] {"a","b","50"});
            Collection<ProposalResponse> resps = channel.sendTransactionProposal(req);

                channel.sendTransaction(resps);

        } 

    /**
     * Utility method to get private key from bytes using Bouncy Castle Security
     * Provider
     * 
     * @param data
     * @return privateKey
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws NoSuchProviderException
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws InvalidKeySpecException
     */
    private PrivateKey getPrivateKeyFromBytes(byte[] data)
            throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        final Reader pemReader = new StringReader(new String(data));
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        final PrivateKeyInfo pemPair;
        try (PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(pemReader)) {
            pemPair = (PrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();
        }

        PrivateKey privateKey = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
                .getPrivateKey(pemPair);

        return privateKey;
    }

    /**
     * Find files ending with _sk
     * 
     * @param directorys
     * @return file
     */
    private File findFileSk(String directorys) {

        File directory = new File(directorys);

        File[] matches = directory.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.endsWith("_sk"));

        if (null == matches) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    format("Matches returned null does %s directory exist?", directory.getAbsoluteFile().getName()));
        }

        if (matches.length != 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException(format("Expected in %s only 1 sk file but found %d",
                    directory.getAbsoluteFile().getName(), matches.length));
        }

        return matches[0];
    }
}
```

The setting up crypto materials part and the channel initialization part works fine (adding peer and order to the channel and initializing it)

I get errors during QueryProposal or a TransactionProposal, that is , if I want to do anything after initializing channel with the required crypto material

This is the error trace:

> Message Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException:
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: Channel
>   mychannel failed proposal on peer peer0.org1.example.com
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.TransactionException:
>   org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.exception.ProposalException: getConfigBlock
>   for channel mychannel failed with peer peer0.org1.example.com. Status
>   FAILURE, details: Channel Channel{id: 1, name: mychannel} Sending
>   proposal with transaction:
>   3323e96e7e9147ccee2491b310e6dacfc2db93d50578f08a43a5c997a211135a to
>   Peer{ id: 7, name: peer0.org1.example.com, channelName: mychannel,
>   url: grpcs://localhost:7051} failed because of: gRPC
>   failure=Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=io exception,
>   cause=io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException:
>   Connection refused: no further information:
>   localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7051

I have tried changing docker images, did not work, same error, I have a feeling that this error has something to do with grpcs refusing to connect with the peer on the port? Is there something that i have missed or something that can prevent from accessing the peer. Somewhere is the port already used, or a firewall maybe ? Because this worked in another system with the same steps. Not really sure about this.
Suggestions would help !

Thanks

Comment: I **think** you need to [setup a virtual network channel between your two docker images](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) (or an [overlay](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/)). Make sure "peer0.org1.example.com" is correct for your configuration. Honestly it's hard to tell without more context. Why do you have `ordererProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", "orderer.example.com");` ? And `Orderer orderer = hfClient.newOrderer("orderer.example.com", "grpcs://localhost:7050");` ??? that looks like public samples that need to be changed - or read from the environment (12-factors)

Comment: this is just the example sample given in the hyperledger fabric java sdk test. I think the "hostnameOverride" tells that you can use localhost, or ordere.example.com, anything should be fine. I dont think that would be a problem, since the exact same code works in another machine with the same setup properly

Comment: is there a configuration that i have missed with docker or grpcs that prevents the connection. I think there is something that is refusing connection there. Or are you saying that the hostname could be an issue here ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your hostnames are just wrong. That's what the message "getConfigBlock for channel mychannel failed with peer peer0.org1.example.com" is telling you. That is pointing pretty firmly at `peerProperties.setProperty("hostnameOverride", "peer0.org1.example.com");` - but it's really hard to tell. And I can't tell why you're overriding the hostname in the first place.

Comment: so i just remove the property ?

Comment: Or set it to the correct value. Where correct value is visible from the peer to your ledger. I assumed you were filling it with the correct value for your configuration. If you literally copied and pasted, you're going to have to reevaluate everywhere you have done so and put the correct values for your hosts. I don't know what or where your hosts are. So it's very difficult for me to help more.

Comment: If you go [back to the docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/build_network.html), did you setup the [environment variables](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/build_network.html#create-join-channel)? And run `./byfn.sh up`? It looks like you missed at least one step.

Comment: did the steps yes. upped the byfn network.as well. i am follwing the byfn tutorial only for your referece. ill change the host name and try. else any suggestions ? are you sure there isnt something that is not allowing grpcs to connect ? also i am using Docker toolbox and the not the docker desktop. i presume that would not make a difference

Comment: You're following a tutorial I didn't write and you didn't link to. I googled it. And I don't know, for sure, which version you found. But it appears the tutorial is deprecated. Don't know what else to tell you.